# Magento: Getting Discounted price

Tags: magento

We have a mixture of products, some with specialPrice and some with Catalog Rules set.

I need to display the discounted % for all my products on my frontend.

We were using $_product->getSpecialPrice() to get the discounted price, but this fails for products which prices based on catalog rules.

Is it possible to get the Discounted prices based on the catalog rule or from the specialPrice ?

Comment: Try $_product->getFinalPrice()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this snippet:
This one will calculate price rules.

```
    Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->calcProductPriceRule($product,$product->getPrice());
```

Is is what you looking for?

Comment: Is there a faster way to pull this data? Surely product pages are not pulling prices like this?

Comment: Currently I think there is 1 way. Particularly on the stage where product collection is formed. So if you need such custom behaviour I would suggest to write you a custom module with custom resource module where joining with rules table and applying rules is implemented.

Answer (score 14):

Yes you can use `$_product->getFinalPrice()`.

Here is the difference in the three prices:

`$regularPrice = number_format($_product->getPrice(), 2);`

`$discountedPrice = number_format($_product->getFinalPrice(), 2);`

`$specialPrice = number_format($_product->getSpecialPrice(), 2);`